# Ionic v1 $state.go not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

this is my first post, I hope I'm clear enough, I can't get $state.go to work, I've been searching all over but I don't seem to find the answer, not too sure what I'm doing wrong because I'm new to this technology which I think is actually really good. Maybe I have to declare index.html in the app.js but I do not want this page to be accessible once the app is started, only for the beginning, once the users have logged in, this screen will not be seen anymore unless they restart the app.

1. This is my app.js

   ```
   angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

   .config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   $stateProvider

   .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
   })

   .state('tab.appointments', {
    url: '/appointments',
    views: {
     'tab-appointments': {
       templateUrl: 'templates/tab-appointments.html',
       controller: 'appointmentsCtrl'
     }
    }
   })

   .state('tab.findPatient', {
    url: '/findPatient',
    views: {
     'tab-findPatient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-findPatient.html',
      controller: 'FindPatientCtrl'
     }
    }
   }) 

   .state('tab.findSlot', {
    url: '/findSlot',
    views: {
     'tab-findPatient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-findSlot.html',
      controller: 'FindPatientCtrl'
      }
     }
   })

   .state('tab.settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    views: {
     'tab-settings': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
      controller: 'settingsCtrl'
      }
    }
   });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/appointments');
   });
   ```
2. This is my index.html

   ```
    <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm" align-title="center"></ion-header-bar>
    <ion-pane>
     <ion-content scroll="false">
      <form ng-controller="loginCtrl" name="loginCredentialsForm">
       <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
         <input class="text-center" type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" required="true">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
         <input class="text-center" type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required="true">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
         <input class="text-center" type="password" maxlength=4 placeholder="PIN" ng-model="practicePin" required="true">
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="text-center">
         <button class="button button-block button-calm small_button" ng-disabled="loginCredentialsForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()" type="submit">Login</button>
       </div>
      </form>
     </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
    </body>
   ```
3. And this is my controllers.js

   ```
   angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

      $scope.login = function() {
      $state.go('tab.appointments');
     };
   })
   ```

Thanks in advance, I do apologize for any syntax mistakes.

Edited - added

1. This is what tabs.html looks like

   ```
   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-bottom tabs-calm">
     <ion-tab title="Appointments" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/appointments">
     <ion-nav-view name="tab-appointments">
     </ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>
   ```
2. And then there's home.html which I'm pretty sure is the one that redirects to tabs.html and then been loaded by the rest.

   ```
      <body ng-app="starter">
       <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm" align-title="center">
         <ion-nav-back-button>
         </ion-nav-back-button>
       </ion-nav-bar>
       <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </body>
   ```

If I change the name of home.html to index.html and don't use the actual index.html that I want for people to log in everything works fine, but I really need that people logs in so they have their own records.

[This is what home.html actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f15e5.png)
As I said, I'm new to this kind of technology, trying to do my best to understand how this works. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have errors in developer tools console? Also do you have '<div ui-view></div>' in `templates/tabs.html`?

Comment: I've just modified the template that ionic gives as an example, should I anyways?

Comment: Additionally, the `ui-view` in `templates/tabs.html` should have a name attribute of `tab-appointments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `$window` for redirect to a page.

```
 $window.location.href = 'templates/tab-appointments.html';
```

your controller can be changed like this

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

 .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state,$window) {

   $scope.login = function() {
    $window.location.href = 'templates/tab-appointments.html'; 
  };
})
```

Comment: This actually made the trick pretty well, you are even able to validate inputs before redirecting to the other page via JS. I really appreciate you answer